# Why does this contrived Java code deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, deadlock

I'm having a hard time understanding `synchronized`. Since the first thread doesn't do anything with the object 2, doesn't it "unlock" everything in a second?

```
public class Uninterruptible {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Object o1 = new Object(); final Object o2 = new Object();

        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized(o1) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        synchronized(o2) {}
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("t1 interrupted"); }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized(o2) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        synchronized(o1) {}
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("t2 interrupted"); }
            }
        };

        t1.start(); t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        t1.interrupt(); t2.interrupt();
        t1.join(); t2.join();

        System.out.println("Donezo!");

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect ?
For me it's going to do: 
t1 lock 21, t1 sleep
t2 lock o2, t2, sleep
t1 can't get o2, t1 blocked.
t2 can't get o1, t2 blocked.
t1 interrupted, t2 could.

Comment: This is a classic example of what happens if two threads lock the same two resources in different orders.  Neither thread actually makes it into the inner `synchronized` block since it can't acquire the needed resource because the other thread has it locked.  Not sure what you are expecting, but this is covered in every single threading tutorial in existence.  If you find a tutorial where this is NOT one of the first topics covered, discard it immediately.

Comment: This is a classic deadlock. Each process needs two resources. First process obtains o1 but can't obtain o2, since 2nd process already locked it.  The second process will not be able to get o1 for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @PM77-1 Note that it also could be t2 obtaining o2 first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter that the inner `synchronized` blocks do nothing.  Java will still attempt to acquire the lock on the the object specified.

No matter whether you have nothing or a huge amount of processing in the inner `synchronized` blocks, what you have is the minimal example to create a deadlock: two different threads, each owning the lock on a distinct resource, each attempting to acquire the lock on each other's resource.

The deadlock occurs before either thread even gets to executing the inner `synchronized` block, because neither thread can get locks on both resources at the same time.

The code winds up doing nothing but hanging, with each thread blocked.  Your calls to `interrupt` are too late to cause an `InterruptedException`; they only set the "interrupted status" in the `Thread`.  Commenting out `Thread.sleep(2000)` will let the calls to `interrupt` catch the `Thread`s while they are still sleeping, before they even attempt to acquire the second lock.